# How to read and display file data using int86 function with REGS struct for 8086 in C-Language

Tags: c, assembly, dos, x86-16, windows-98

I have a text file with some content I have to move the cursor in from relative to the BOF and display its content on the screen using int 21h/42h.

here is the code I am working on. I am using windows 98 (16-bit DOS)in VM and it's part of my system programming assignment so I have to use it tried in Turbo c++ with DOSBox but It has some issues.

on printing **buff** it displays random values

## Code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <bios.h>
#include <dos.h>

unsigned int handle;
char buff[50];

void main(){

    union REGS regs; // set pointer
    union REGS regs_r; // read file
    handle = open("text.txt", O_RDONLY);
    
    // set pointer to BOF (Begenning of File)
    regs.x.bx = handle;
    regs.h.ah = 0x42; // LSEEK
    regs.h.al = 0x00 // Mode (0) BOF
    regs.x.cx = 0;
    regs.x.dx = 0;
    int86(0x21, &regs, &regs);
    
    
    // read the file
    
    regs_r.x.bx = handle;
    regs_r.x.cx = 0x07; Bytes to read ?
    regs_r.h.ah = 0x3fh; 
    regs_r.x.dx = (unsigned int) buff; // buffer for data
    int86(0x21, &regs_r, &regs_r);
    
    printf("DATA : %c", buff);
    
    
    getch();
    clrscr();
}
```

here are some reference links

- [8086 int
  21h/42h](https://jbwyatt.com/253/emu/8086_bios_and_dos_interrupts.html#int21h_42h)
- [asm move File
  Pointer](http://vitaly_filatov.tripod.com/ng/asm/asm_010.67.html)

any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You need to set `ds` as well. The difficult question is figuring out what your C compiler uses ...

Comment: what will be in ds?

Comment: Whatever your C compiler uses. Maybe it has some macros to access the segment of a pointer?

Comment: nope I did not, I also try to embed assembly code in C with asm{.....} but it also didn't work, **buff** remains the same. unable to access data.

Comment: It might depend on the memory model. Turbo C++ had various tiny, small, compact, etc. models.

Comment: @WeatherVane, Turbo C++ has some issue it gets closed on calling int86 so now I am running my code in Borland C++ For MS-DOS in Windows 98.

Comment: AFAIR there are macros in `dos.h` being `FP_SEG(&x)` and `FP_OFF(&x)`. By 'Turbo C++' I mean 'Borland Turbo C++' RIP.

Comment: Don't know how to use them .... hates that low-level coding it's low 16-bit. shit.
so I can do ``FP_SEG(&x)`` where x could be **buff**?

Comment: Have a look at the macros. Compare with `printf("%p\n", buff);` Suck it and see. Be aware of the difference between `buff` and `&buff` with an array. Perhps the guys on [SE Retrocomputing](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/) are still dabbling with Windows 98.

Comment: when I used ``regs_r.x.dx = FP_OFF(buff)`` then on ``printf("%p",buff)`` I get weird number and on ``printf("%c", buff)`` it shows ``h`` but the content in file is **System Programming**

Comment: `regs_r.x.dx = FP_OFF(buff)` should have the same effect as `regs_r.x.dx = (unsigned int)buff`. In addition, you have to set `ds` to `FP_SEG(buff)`. `ds` is located in the `SREGS` structure, not in the `REGS` structure. You need to use the function `int86x()` instead of `int86()` to deal with the `SREGS` structure.

Answer (score 0):

To get the data-segment you could try this way:
Declare a far pointer and assign to it the address of your buffer and recast it.

```
char buffer[100];
char far *ptr = (char far *)&buffer;
```

now take the 16 most significant bits from the pointer paying attention to the complement of the sign

```
unsigned long addr_value = (unsigned long)ptr;
unsigned int data_segment = (unsigned int)(addr_value >> 16);
```

It should work.

Comment: which value should I assign to ``regs_r.x.dx``

Comment: = (unsigned int)addr_value & 0xffff;