# How do I print output from int86

Tags: c, assembly, x86-16

I'm trying to understand the concept of int86 function. I want to print the lines it read from the file on console, and display Print error message (if any) in opening or moving the file pointer (after checking FLAG variable defined in the REGS union)

```
#include<STDIO.H>
#include<FCNTL.H>
#include<IO.H>
#include<BIOS.H>
#include<DOS.H>
unsigned int handle;
void main()
{
    union REGS regs;
    unsigned long int size;
    handle = open("C:\filed", O_RDONLY);
    regs.x.bx = handle;
    regs.h.ah = 0x42;
    regs.h.al = 0x02;

    regs.x.cx = 0;
    regs.x.dx = 0;

    int86(0x21, &regs, &regs);
    printf (regs);
    getch();
}
```

Comment: You can send a (`$`-terminated) string to `STDOUT` with interrupt `0x21` function `0x09` (if you have MS-DOS). But if you are writing in C and there are C library functions to do these jobs, then use them. If there are jobs which the library doesn't cover, then use the system calls. But if you are practising assembler, use an assembler not C.

Comment: Note that `printf (regs);` isn't going to work *at all*.

Comment: @WeatherVane: No doubt, but he has no idea how to do it. If I were actually coding in assembly I'd be able to do it but I can't seem to recall how to deal with it in the regs structure like this.

Comment: @Joshua this is Borland Turbo C++?

Comment: @WeatherVane: I believe it is.

Comment: MS-DOS interrupt `0x21` function `0x42` is the **seek** function, in this case to 0 bytes from the end of the file. So this isn't a route to *reading* from the file, which hasn't yet been tried. So there isn't any file data to print.

Comment: @Joshua yes I'm using Turbo C++
Here regs.h.al = 0x02 is used to move pointer relative to End Of File (EOF)
I tried changing it to 0x00 which is used to move the pointer relative to Beginning of File (BOF)

Also I have to use interrupt 21H/42H using INT86()

there has to be a use of int86 but I don't how do i print the whats read from int86()

Comment: @WeatherVane How do I use it to to seek from beginning of the file? inorder to read the text from file

Comment: You don't need to: you just opened the file, and the file pointer is positioned at the start of the file. But what you previously wrote was correct: set `al` to `0` for an offset from the BOF.

Comment: Bear in mind that a block-oriented file handler isn't really suitable for reading a text file (unless one byte at a time). I suggest you write the code to read a string in C first, using the low level file handling functions like `open()`, and then convert the code to the appropriate system calls. You could use interrupt `0x21` function `0x3F` to read a block of bytes from the file.

Comment: @WeatherVane I changed `regs.h.al = 0x02` to `regs.h.al = 0x00` Now it throws an error Cannot Convert 'REGS' to const char *
Type mismatch in parameter '__format' in call to 'printf(const char*,...)'

Comment: Note that `printf (regs);` isn't going to work at all. I don't know what your intention is. You haven't actually read any data from the file yet. Perhaps you can find a tutorial somewhere, that takes you through it all.

Comment: I have to use `0x21` function `0x42`

Comment: That is used to set the file pointer position, for the next read or write operation. It doesn't read any data from the file.

Comment: Note that `"C:\filed"` doesn't do what you think it does; `\f` is an escape sequence producing a form feed.  Make sure to write `"C:\\filed"` to get the desired file name.

Comment: Yesterday, there was [another question about `int86`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70248289/how-to-read-and-display-file-data-using-int86-function-with-regs-struct-for-8086); maybe this will help you also.